# Can't get the value from session to index in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have this link in the comment

I have an issue in this code: can anyone help?
cant print the value in the index I have horoscope and I did the list but not want to print the value. in the index when I click the save button the date print in the console but not in the div can anyone help me?

Javascript

```
function add() {
    let url = "./server/addhoroscope.php"
    let method = "POST"
    let formData = new FormData()
    let theDate = document.getElementById('inpdate').value;
    formData.set("date", theDate)
    makeRequest("./server/addhoroscope.php", "POST", formData, (result) => {
        console.log(result)
        // console.log($fromMonthAndDay)
    })
}

function makeRequest(url, method, formData, callback) {
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'post',
        body: formData
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        return response.json()
    }).then((result) => {
        callback(result)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error: ", err)
    })
};

function showTheDate() {
    let url = "./server/viewHoroscope.php"
    let method = "GET"
    fetch(url, {
        method: method,
    }).then((Response) => {
        return Response.json()
    }).then((body) => {
        if (body) {
            echo("hej");
        } else {
            echo("hej");
        }
        let contant = document.getElementById("outPUT");
        contant.innerText = body;
    }).catch((err) => {})
};
```

PHP

```
<?php
session_start();    
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'GET') {
if(isset($_SESSION['horoscope'])) {
    $horos = $_SESSION['horoscope'];    
    echo json_encode($horos);
} else {
    echo json_encode('');}} 
?>
```

Comment: you haven't the set value in session how can you expect the value in that session item.

Comment: yes, the list in another file Horoskop_list.php check: github.com/nawarmohra/Horoskop-2019.git

Comment: I am not getting it. anyways you can also create your own session item as well. and then assign the required value and finally access it.

Comment: Look at online javascript beautifiers, it will show you indentation.  It will help a lot in reading your code (and for you to find bugs).

Comment: Hi @Leen, if you are still facing the same problem try debugging it by printing the session global variable and return it to your javascript response and then log it to console using console.log. For printing session variable use print_r($_SESSION). Then see if your value is adding to session variable at the end of your addHoroscope.php script. Then also print session variable in the index.php sript for debugginh. This manner you can find your way out and debug your code. All the best.